# How can I make my CRUD application work offline?

Tags: javascript, crud

I have simple CRUD application with the backend written in Flask, datastore is Mongo and frontend in AngularJS.

I would like to augment the application to allow for CRUD operations even when it's offline and automatically sync when a data connection is available. What is the best correct technology to do this with the minimum amount of extra development?

I've looked at Meteor which could solve the problem but would involve re-writting the app in Meteor.

I've also looked at Breeze which look like it might be a better option and allow me to keep using Angular and Flask.

Comment: First thing came to my mind is `Breeze`

Comment: i would just break the saving and storing into two parts. save to a buffer as soon as the data is made. the buffer can use localStorage or indexedDB to persist data medium-term. flush the buffer to a store in the background. if store is unreachable, no problem, just keep buffering and trying.

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-html5db/

Answer (score 2):

Is it a lot of data? Adding offline capabilities to an existing application will always have some impact.

You could try using some HTML5 features directly: [HTML5 Application Caching](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/) is made for offline access and allows to download all the needed artifacts for the webapp to be able to work offline, so that solves a part of the problem.

The other part is the the data, it could be loaded into the browser using either the browser [HTML5 Local Storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) or [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/IndexedDB).

Local Storage allows to store String associated to keys, so for storing JSON you need to stringify it first. IndexedDB supports more data types,both datastores have a Javascript API.

So it would be a matter of choosing one datastore and making a sync module that periodically pings back the server and when the connection is available sync the local datastore.

The alternative is to use some offline first framework like [hoodie](http://hood.ie/), this an [article](http://www.roberthorvick.com/2013/06/30/todomvc-angularjs-hood-ie-60-minutes-to-awesome/) from a hoodie developer for how to use hoodie together with angular.  He took the Angular [TODO sample application](http://todomvc.com/architecture-examples/angularjs/) and modified it to use hoodie.

This together with application cache might be a lower impact way to get offline capability to your Angular app.

Comment: No it's not a lot of data at all. Definitely less than 100MB. I'm more concerned about the extra development required: for example changing the Angular services to fallback to the local store automatically.

Comment: That's a lot of data for browser storage, local storage only allows a few MB, and IndexedDB requires the user manual permission for more than 50MB, limits are browser dependent. But if you minimize the data and use a combination of IndexedDB and Application Caching, offline is feasible with the solution above.